# How do I make CTRL-SHIFT-S bind to Save All in Atom?

Tags: electron, atom-editor, key-bindings

I tried to follow the directions in the Keybindings settings, but it didn't work.

[image]

I copied the default entry, opened the keymap file, pasted, changed to 'all', and saved.

```
'body':
  'ctrl-shift-S': 'core:save-all'
```

I changed two files then presses CTRL-SHIFT-S but they still had the blue modified marker.

I tried the 'keybinding resolver' mentioned in the comments with CTRL-., and it seems to recognize what I created, but it's not saving all files.

[image]

Atom 1.27.2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to change the `core` to `window`

```
'body':
  'ctrl-shift-S':'window:save-all'
```

See https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/9390

Comment: Wow not intuitive at all, especially since Save All is right below Save As in the menu.